# Sparql delete entity and all its linked elements

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I have a Fuseki DB with triples like the following:

```
<https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#row=1>
<https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#ws7col0>
"ws6dat1aa"
...
<https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#row=2>
<https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#ws6col2>
"ws6dat2aa"
...
<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#bottomDataProperty>
<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#propertyDisjointWith>
<https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#ws7col0>
```

I want to delete everything related to:

```
<https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#row=1>
```

The problem is that i'm not able to write a query that also target triples like that one:

```
<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#bottomDataProperty>
<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#propertyDisjointWith>
<https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#ws7col0>
```

I have used the following query to delete triples about a list of entities:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
DELETE { 
  ?x ?y ?z
} 
WHERE { 
  {
   ?x ?y ?z.
   ?x rdfs:seeAlso <https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/#dcat_test.csv-WSP1WS6>.
  }
  union
    {
   ?x ?y ?z.
   ?x rdfs:seeAlso <https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/#dcat_test.csv-WSP1WS7>.
  }
}
```

I think i have to do something similar to that:
[SPARQL: Delete instance and all of its properties with linked subproperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129752/sparql-delete-instance-and-all-of-its-properties-with-linked-subproperties) but i'm stuck. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you specify "related"? And after that maybe you can explain me why do you expect the target triple to be deleted as well then?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work if you want to delete the resource entirely from the graph.  Note that you need to remove the triples "both ways".

```
DELETE { 
  <https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#row=1> ?p ?o .
  ?s1 ?p1 <https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#row=1> .
} 
WHERE { 
   <https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#row=1> ?p ?o .
   OPTIONAL {
      ?s1 ?p1 <https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#row=1> .
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply. Your query still keeps triples like the following in the db and i need to delete them...

<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#bottomDataProperty>
<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subPropertyOf>
<https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#ws6col0>

Comment: Do you mean triples such as {<https://tomcat.antudo.it/data/bucket.json-WSP1WS8#row=1> <w3.org/2002/07/owl#bottomDataProperty> ?o} ?  If so, what is the architecture of your triples?  Are there multiple named graphs?  You may be deleting from one and querying against the aggregate of all graphs.