# How is India related to “Indira Gandhi”? (no need to find all existing relationships, but find at least an interesting one)

Tags: json, sparql, dbpedia

I wonder using SparQL to express "How is India related to “Indira Gandhi”? (no need to find all existing relationships, but find at least an interesting one)?"
under http://dbpedia.org/sparql to explore DBPedia(the RDF-ized version of Wikipedia)

An example query I have:

```
SELECT ?relationship 
WHERE { ?s rdf:type dbo:Country . 
        ?s rdfs:label "India"@en . 
        ?x a dbo:Person . 
        ?x rdfs:label "Indira Gandhi"@en . 
        ?x ?p ?s . 
        ?p rdfs:label ?relationship . 
        filter lang(?relationship = "en") 
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: What? What's the question here? Does it even have anything to do with programming?

Comment: Please search for "find all paths between two nodes with SPARQL" - this has been asked several times before. And please provide a starting SPARQL query. It doesn't make sense to show you the query if you don't know anything about SPARQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SPARQL: is there any path between two nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916040/sparql-is-there-any-path-between-two-nodes)

Comment: Upon rereading I think it's not quite a duplicate. It's still very unclear what you're after though. What is an 'interesting' relationship? Show what you've tried sofar and where exactly you're stuck. [edit] your question to add more details. Also have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution (direct relationship) you can use this:

```
SELECT ?relation
WHERE 
{
    dbr:Indira_Gandhi ?relation dbr:India.
}
```

To find another indirect relationship between two nodes, read about finding paths between nodes.