# Using SPARQL find path to a node connected by a specific relationship

Tags: graph, sparql, rdf, graph-algorithm, triplestore

Given a RDF graph and a starting node, I want to find all paths from that starting node to a node which is a *Subject* of an input relationship/ predicate. The RDF graph is stored in a triple store.

Example triples:

```
<A, *hasRelationship1*, B>  
<B, *hasRelationship2*, C>  
<B, *hasRelationship3*, C>  
<B, *hasRelationship4*, F>  
<C, *hasRelationship5*, D>  
<D, *hasRelationship6*, E>
```

Given input A, I want to find all paths to a node which is *Subject* of *hasRelationship6* (in example above that node is D). Also there are two paths from A->D in this example.

Would SPARQL be the right tool to get this answer? If yes any suggestions on the SPARQL query for above use case?

Or would the suggestion be to first find the *Subject* for *hasRelationship6* and then run a graph algorithm to find paths between A and D? If yes, any suggested graph algorithm libraries which can run on SPARQL end points/ triple stores?

For my use case runtime query (or graph traversal) performance would be important.

Thanks

Comment: SPARQL is definitely the wrong language for graph traversal. depending on the graph database, Gremlin, Cypher, etc. are indeed better.

Comment: also, this question came up many times, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024413/finding-all-steps-in-property-path for example, how dumb it is via SPARQL

Comment: Thanks for responding! 
we are using RDF stored in a triple store, so Cypher and gremlin are not an option. Thanks for the link. i will definitely take a look. 
Are there any libraries which can run on triple stores for doing graph traversals?