# Expand path between subject and object in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This SPARQL query returns `true`:

```
ASK {
  wd:Q216665 wdt:P279* wd:Q5185279 .
  }
```

https://w.wiki/6Mi5

Is there any way to expand the path (i.e. `wdt:P279*`) to better understand the link between subject and predicate?

Comment: getting paths in SPARQL is rather tricky, but possible with property path and an intermediate node to at least get edges: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024413/finding-all-steps-in-property-path

Comment: a more efficient way on the Blazegraph backend of Wikidata: `#defaultView:Graph
PREFIX gas: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/gas#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?linkTo  ?linkToLabel
WHERE {
  SERVICE gas:service {
    gas:program gas:gasClass "com.bigdata.rdf.graph.analytics.SSSP" ;
    gas:in wd:Q216665 ;
    gas:traversalDirection "Forward" ;
    gas:out ?item ;
   gas:target wd:Q5185279 ;
   gas:out1 ?depth ;
  gas:maxIterations 6 ;
   gas:linkType wdt:P279 .
  }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P279 ?linkTo . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}`

Comment: That's cool, thank you very much. For who doesn't understand (like myself) what the above query does, here's a page with some hints: https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/RDF_GAS_API

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that the path's lenght is *at most* N, then you can hardcode it.

E.g. with N = 4:

```
SELECT ?start ?node1 ?node2 ?node3 ?end WHERE {
  BIND (wd:Q216665 as ?start)
  BIND (wd:Q5185279 as ?end)
  { ?start wdt:P279 ?node1 . ?node1 wdt:P279 ?end . } UNION
  { ?start wdt:P279 ?node1 . ?node1 wdt:P279 ?node2 . ?node2 wdt:P279 ?end . } UNION
  { ?start wdt:P279 ?node1 . ?node1 wdt:P279 ?node2 . ?node2 wdt:P279 ?node3 . ?node3 wdt:P279 ?end . }
}
```

or even:

```
SELECT ?start ?node1 ?node2 ?node3 ?end WHERE {
  BIND (wd:Q216665 as ?start)
  BIND (wd:Q5185279 as ?end)
  ?start wdt:P279* ?end .
  OPTIONAL { ?start wdt:P279 ?node1 . ?node1 wdt:P279+ ?end .
  OPTIONAL { ?node1 wdt:P279 ?node2 . ?node2 wdt:P279+ ?end .
  OPTIONAL { ?node2 wdt:P279 ?node3 . ?node3 wdt:P279+ ?end .
  }}}
}
```