# Imitate behaviour of Wikidata tree in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to reproduce the Wikidata generic tree behaviour ([like this](https://wikidata-todo.toolforge.org/tree.html?q=Q3314483&rp=279&depth=1)) in SPARQL. The concept is that we have an initial tag (`Fruit` (Q3314483)) and we can change the depth of the tree to get the child of the initial. For example:

```
- Q3314483 (Fruit)
-- Q89 (Apple)
-- Q169 (Mango)
---- Q599314 (Osteen)
---- Q2663618 (Alphonso)
-- Q196 (Cherry)
...
```

I am stuck with SPARQL query as I never worked with it before.
In particular, there is the thing that I looked for but the problem I can not add depth parameter to this snippet:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P279* wd:Q3314483.
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }
}
```

Can you please help of how to change the script to limit the depth equals 1 to get only the following:

```
- Q3314483 (Fruit)
-- Q89 (Apple)
-- Q169 (Mango)
-- Q196 (Cherry)
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you omit the `*`, you get only direct subclasses. Is that what you mean?

Comment: the tool is incrementally getting the direct subclasses to expand the tree. SPARQL property path had a feature like `wdt:P279{1,3}` in the proposal, but it never made it to the final specs. So all you can do is to do `wdt:P279/wdt:P279?/wdt:P279?` - but property paths are really expensive. Also, keeping track of the depth of the path or the paths only works with limitations and is cumbersome, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024413/finding-all-steps-in-property-path/18032019#18032019 - but to get just depth 1 is trivial as the comment above already said, just do `wdt:P279`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `wdt:P279*`, you are asking for any (even empty) path from the subject and the object of your triple.

If you don't want to allow a generic path buth ask only for direct subclasses, you can just remove the asterisk `*`.

Then, if you wish to ask for path of specific lenght, you can build them as `wdt:P279/wdt:P279` (length 2), `wdt:P279/wdt:P279/wdt:P279` (length 3), etc.